# Looping through an object and changing all values

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble looping through an object and changing all the values to something else, let's say I want to change all the values to the string "redacted". I need to be able to do this in pure JavaScript.

For example I'd have an object like this...

```
spy = {
id: 007,
name: "James Bond",
age: 31
};
```

and the object would look like this after...

```
spy = {
id: "redacted",
name: "redacted",
age: "redacted"
};
```

Here is what I have to start with

```
var superSecret = function(spy){
  // Code Here
}
```

This shouldn't create a new spy object but update it.

Comment: You can use `Object.keys(spy)` to get the property names, then loop over that using say *forEach*. Lots of questions and answers here on that.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

try

```
var superSecret = function(spy){
  Object.keys(spy).forEach(function(key){ spy[key] = "redacted" });
  return spy;
}
```

Comment: Man giving me an error of function returned undefined :(

Comment: Just `return spy;`

Comment: Just face palmed myself. I appreciate the help! Been a while since I've played with JavaScript.

Comment: @RayonDabre thanks, though OP gave no indication of whether he wants to use the retured value :)

Comment: @gurvinder372, My comment was for OP as he was expecting something in return ;)

Comment: Does not work at all, even with `return spy;`, still returns undefined. I have tried every possible way to access the resulting individual values and just output them via console.log, and nothing works.

Comment: @AdmiralAdama please share a fiddle so that I can look into your attempt.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Actually, I got a tip from a colleague that the above code simply stores the function, and that to instantiate the variable, I must subsequently add `superSecret();` or something. Can you verify? (Sorry, new to javascript).

Answer (score 33):

You can also go functional.

Using `Object.keys` is better as you will only go through the object properties and not it's prototype chain.

`Object.keys(spy).reduce((acc, key) => {acc[key] = 'redacted'; return acc; }, {})`

Comment: To extend this to altering the values in the starting object (eg, adding 1 to each value if the values are numbers), change `acc[key] = 'redacted'` to `acc[key] = spy[key] + 1`.

Answer (score 15):

A nice solution is using a combination of [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) - which doesn't alter the original object;

```
var superSecret = function(spy){
  return Object.keys(spy).reduce(
    (attrs, key) => ({
      ...attrs,
      [key]: 'redacted',
    }),
    {}
  );
}
```

Comment: Are there performance implications for copying the accumulator to a new object at each iteration? Seems like this could be done by preserving a single accumulator object throughout.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a more simple version:

```
  Object.keys(spy).forEach(key => {
    spy[key] = 'redacted';
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a little helper function that walks through an object and applies a callback to each entry:

```
iterateEntries(node, fn) {
    const newNode = {};
    Object.entries(node).forEach(([key, val]) => (newNode[key] = fn(val)));
    return newNode;
}
```

Usage:

```
iterateEntries(yourObject, (entry) => {
  return entry; // do something with entry here
});
```

Comment: This is better written than the accepted answer because it is not mutating the input of the function, instead creating a `newNode`

Answer (score 5):

```
var superSecret = function(spy){
    for(var key in spy){
          if(spy.hasOwnProperty(key)){
               //code here
               spy[key] = "redacted"; 
            }
     }
   return spy;    
}
```

Comment: I found this to be a most useful solution for my particular use case. Upvoted, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Old question but I see that the checked solution have some "problems", this is the one that should acutally work:

```js
Object.keys(myArray).forEach(i => {myArray[i] = "redacted"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a proxy:

```
function superSecret(spy) {
  return new Proxy(spy, { get() { return "redacted"; } });
}

> superSecret(spy).id
< "redacted"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change object values based condition

```
const user = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'john.doe@example.com',
};

// iterate over the user object

for (const key in user) {
   user.hasOwnProperty(key)? user[key] === 'John Doe'? user[key] = "ali" : false : false 
   console.log(`${key}: ${user[key]}`);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
let dataArray = [
            {
                total: 112,
                tax: 51,
                key:0,
            },
            {
                total: 58,
                tax: 53,
                key:0,
            }
        ];

dataArray.map((data, i) => {
   dataArray[i].key = data.total - data.tax;
});

console.log(dataArray);
```

Comment: It's not an array, it's an object