# Remove the extra space in object value

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to remove the extra space inside of the object value.

```
const object = {
    primaryInformation: {
       firstName: "John  Doe",
       lastName: "Doe     Space"
    }
}
```

Is there any simplest way to remove the extra space between the words of object value using `map`?

**Expected Output**

```
firstName: "John Doe",
lastName: "Doe Space"
```

Comment: I'm trying to remove the space using object not a single string. Is there any chance that we can map all object value then remove the string?

Comment: The field in the object is still a string, you can apply a string replace code while doing a `.map` assuming you have an array of objects

Comment: @Dave not with `Array.prototype.map`, since that's just a function for arrays

Comment: You can recursively go through every nested layer of the object

Comment: Combine [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36467369/looping-through-an-object-and-changing-all-values) with [the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space) and you should be fine. If it doesn't work, you can [edit] your question showing how you're trying to combine them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the object structure in your question, I've written this loop.

```js
const object = {
  primaryInformation: {
    firstName: "John  Doe",
    lastName: "Doe     Space"
  }
};

for (const key in object) {
  const value = object[key];

  for (const key2 in value) {
    const string = value[key2];

    value[key2] = string.replace(/  +/g, " ");
  }
}

console.log(object);
```